# How to access a specific directory in Docker?

Tags: docker-compose, xmlhttprequest

My app loads under Docker-compose. Here is the .yml file. I am developing on my local PC. I am trying to access the Docker running server using XMLHttpRequest from an extension. The path I am trying to access on the docker based server is http://localhost/index.php/Subit_backend/register'. I am getting a 404 error back from the call to xhr.send. I am not sure how to set up Docker to allow me to get that specific "subit_backend" file (or the register function). I am using Codeigniter. Do I need to modify the .yml or the path in the source (which works fine normally)?

[image: .yml file]

Comment: You seem to have attached an image instead of your `docker-compose.yml` file; can you replace this with the text of the file?  Docker on its own doesn't do any sort of path-based routing, only TCP port mapping, so you should also describe a little bit about how the path is supposed to get to the container you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David. Through some debugging of the server code I have concluded that the xhr call is getting through to the server. For some reason the proper record is not being found in the xbase file. I will try to figure the reason, but thAnks again for your help.